# std::mutex и как его все таки нужно использовать для разных участков

Tags: c++

Я все таки окончательно запутался в мьютексах и как их нужно правильно применять к синхронизации разных участков кода:

Вот два простых примера: различаются только доп. наличием переменной std::my_mutex1

1)

```
#include <iostream>           
    #include <thread>             
    #include <mutex>              
    #include <condition_variable> 
    #include <chrono> 
    
    std::mutex my_mutex;
    
    std::condition_variable my_cond_var;
    std::list<int>my_list;
    int global_int;
    
    
    
    void waiting_threads(int id)
    {
    repeat:
    
        std::cout << "waiting_threads_start" << std::endl;
    
        //----------------------------------------------------------------
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> my_lock(my_mutex);
    
    
            while (global_int == 0)
            {
                my_cond_var.wait(my_lock);
            }
            std::cout << "thread_id:" << std::this_thread::get_id() << ":" << id << std::endl; 
    
        }
        //----------------------------------------------------------------
    
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    
        my_mutex.lock();
        global_int = 0;
        my_mutex.unlock();
    
        goto repeat;
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    int main()
    {
        global_int = 0;
    
    
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------Создадим пул потоков:Начало-----------------------------
        std::vector<std::thread> my_thread_vec;
        my_thread_vec.resize(4);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            my_thread_vec[i] = std::thread(waiting_threads, i);     
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------Создадим пул потоков:Конец--------------------
    
    
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    
    
        my_mutex.lock();
        std::cout << "main_start" << std::endl;
        
        global_int = 1;
        my_cond_var.notify_one();    
        global_int = 1;
        my_cond_var.notify_one();   
        global_int = 1;
        my_cond_var.notify_one(); 
        global_int = 1;
        my_cond_var.notify_one();
        
        std::cout << "sleep_main_start" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
        std::cout << "sleep_main_end" << std::endl;
    
        global_int = 1;
        my_cond_var.notify_one();
        std::cout << "main_mutex_end" << std::endl;
        my_mutex.unlock();
    
    
    
        //------------------------------------------------Отпускаем потоки, так как у них бесконечный цикл---------------------------------------
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            my_thread_vec[i].join();
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    }
```

2. 

```
#include <iostream>           
#include <thread>             
#include <mutex>              
#include <condition_variable> 
#include <chrono> 

std::mutex my_mutex;
std::mutex my_mutex1;

std::condition_variable my_cond_var;
std::list<int>my_list;
int global_int;



void waiting_threads(int id)
{
repeat:

    std::cout << "waiting_threads_start" << std::endl;

    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> my_lock(my_mutex);


        while (global_int == 0)
        {
            my_cond_var.wait(my_lock);
        }
        std::cout << "thread_id:" << std::this_thread::get_id() << ":" << id << std::endl; 

    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

    my_mutex.lock();
    global_int = 0;
    my_mutex.unlock();

    goto repeat;
}





int main()
{
    global_int = 0;


    //------------------------------------------------------------------------Создадим пул потоков:Начало-----------------------------
    std::vector<std::thread> my_thread_vec;
    my_thread_vec.resize(4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        my_thread_vec[i] = std::thread(waiting_threads, i);     
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------Создадим пул потоков:Конец--------------------


    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));


    my_mutex1.lock();
    std::cout << "main_start" << std::endl;
    
    global_int = 1;
    my_cond_var.notify_one();    
    global_int = 1;
    my_cond_var.notify_one();   
    global_int = 1;
    my_cond_var.notify_one(); 
    global_int = 1;
    my_cond_var.notify_one();
    
    std::cout << "sleep_main_start" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    std::cout << "sleep_main_end" << std::endl;

    global_int = 1;
    my_cond_var.notify_one();
    std::cout << "main_mutex_end" << std::endl;
    my_mutex1.unlock();



    //------------------------------------------------Отпускаем потоки, так как у них бесконечный цикл---------------------------------------
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        my_thread_vec[i].join();
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

В первом случае изменение значения global_int заблокированы my_mutex, во втором my_mutex1.
Из за этого у код разное поведение.

-В первом случае: потоки пробуждаются только после main_mutex_end - пробуждаются каждый по одному разу и почему то 5ый раз пробуждение не срабатывает.

-Во втором случае: потоки пробуждаются сразу после вызова notify_one() и во втором случае пробуждается один и з потоков и 5ый раз.

Не могу сообразить, что происходит:

-В первом случае создаются 4 потока и в них запускается функция waiting_threads, поток сразу же захватывает my_mutex и так как переменная global_int равна 0, то поток засыпает блокируя остальные потоки. Потом выполнение кода доходит до строки с захватам того же мьютекса в main() и вот тут не понятно, что происходит.

-В втором случае создаются 4 потока и в них запускается функция waiting_threads, поток сразу же захватывает my_mutex и так как переменная global_int равна 0, то поток засыпает блокируя остальные потоки. Потом выполнение кода доходит до строки с захватам my_mutex1 в main()(другого нежели в ф-ии waiting_threads) и вот тут тоже, что то  не понятно, что происходит. Вроде бы участок с кода в котором присутствует обращение к переменной global_int уже под мьютексом my_mutex, а тут захватывается еще один мьютекс my_mutex1 и в участке кода тоже есть обращение к переменной global_int.

Я в конец запутался.

Comment: У вас полное непонимание, как работает `std::condition_variable` да и `std::mutex`. Второй случай вообще непонятно зачем привели, здесь незащищенное обращение к разделяемым данным, рассматривать смысла не имеет - вы можете просто выкинуть `my_mutex1` и не лочить вообще ничего, результат будет темже

Comment: @Slava, но лочить любое обращение к global_int ведь нужно ?

Comment: Нет, любое не нужно, только конкурентное - когда к ней **одновременно** могут обратиться несколько потоков. Опять же вы бросаетесь терминами, которые говорят, что вы просто не понимаете, что происходит. Что вы понимаете под "лочить обращение"? Вы понимаете, что делает мьютекс?

Comment: @Slava, я понимаю это так: мьютекс блокирует одновременное выполнение кода разными потоками и позволет только одному потоку в данный конкретный момент времени выполнять указанный код, который находится под мьютексом. Если это так, то любое обращение к global_int в моем понимании должно быть под мьютексом, потому что в коде есть изменение значения global_int, а к global_int - код с global_int выполняет более одного потока.

Comment: Ну если вы это понимаете, зачем вы пишете код, в котором читающие потоки используют один мьютекс, а пишущий - другой? В результате получается, что только один из читающих потоков (они все на одном мьютексе), но и пишущий поток (он же на другом мьютексе) могут одновременно выполнятся. Что вы пытаетесь этим достичь?

Comment: @Slava, я пытаюсь понять почему в первом случае, когда для чтения и записи я использую один мьютекс, у меня потоки пробуждаются только 4 раза, а не 5 по кол-ву вызванных notify_one().

Comment: Потому, что у вас 4 потока, поэтому просыпаются только 4. Запустите в ожидание 5 потоков, проснутся 5. Я попробую написать ответ, но второй случай я рассматривать не буду, он не имеет смысла.

Comment: @Slava, потока 4, но пробуждаю то я их 5 раз. Но пробуждаются только 4 раза.

Comment: Естественно только 4, потому что `notify_one()` преводит в режим выполнения только один поток, если он ожидает события **в данный момент**. На пятый раз уже никто не ждет, поэтому пятый вызов никого не пробуждает

Comment: @Slava, после выполнения функции, поток опять засыпает в ожидании. И я в 5 раз вызываю notify_one. Разве нет ? Я 4 раза подряд вызвал notify_one, 4 потока пробудились выполнили работу и опять уснули и я в 5 раз пробуждаю их. Разве нет ?

Comment: Я пишу ответ, там попытаюсь расстолковать, что вы не понимаете. Проблема в том, что вы не отпускате мьютекс и не даете тем потокам выполниться. А когда вы мьютекс отпустили, то уже поздно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы не понимаете принцип работы `std::condition_variable`. Давайте начнем с понимания, что делает метод `std::condition_variable::wait()`. А делает он две вещи:

- **атомарно** переводит поток в режим ожидания события и разблокирует мьютекс. Причем то, что это происходит атомарно здесь ключевое, и именно из-за этого `std::condition_variable` и существует.
- по наступлении события (другой поток вызвал `std::condition_variable::notify_one()` или `std::condition_variable::notify_all()` поток переводится из режима ожидания в режим выполнения, и он пытается заблокировть мьютекс и затем продолжить выполнение. Поток может быть также разбужен системными событиями (spurious wakeup).

То есть, во время ожидания события мьютекс разблокирован, но чтобы вернутся из ожидания и продолжить выполнение кода, поток должен быть как разбужен событием (или может быть разбужен например сигналом (spurious wakeup), поэтому условие в ожидании проверяется в цикле) но и опять захватить мьютекс.

Далее, поток, который должен сообщить одному или более ожидающим потокам, что событие наступило делает следующие вещи:

1. блокирует мьютекс
2. устанавливает состояние, которое ожидают
3. посылает сообщение notify_one() или notify_all()
4. разблокирует мьютекс

Причем шаг 3 и шаг 4 можно менять местами.

Что же делает вызов метода `std::condition_variable::notify_one()`? если в данный момент на данной переменной один из потоков ожидает события, то он выводится из режима ожидания. Если таких потоков нет **то вызов `std::condition_variable::notify_one()` игнорируется и не запоминается**

При этом разница между `std::condition_variable::notify_one()` и `std::condition_variable::notify_all()` только в том, что первый метод переведет из режима ожидания только один поток, даже если ожидают многие, а второй их все. Но и в том и в другом случае **поток уже в данный момент должен находится в режиме ожидания, чтобы этот сигнал получить**.

Если вы поймете принцип работы, то вам станет понятен ответ на ваш вопрос

> -В первом случае: потоки пробуждаются только после main_mutex_end - пробуждаются каждый по одному разу и почему то 5ый раз пробуждение не срабатывает.

Потому что вначале на переменной ожидают 4 потока. Вы их все переводите в режим выполнения, но выполниться им не даете, потому что не разблокировали мьютекс. Пятый же вызов проходит вхолостую - на этой переменной события больше никто не ждет.

Кроме того, ваша функция ожидания некорректна, вы не должны сбрасывать переменную в ноль, да еще и после отдельного захвата мьютекса, должна она выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
void waiting_threads(int id)
{
    std::cout << "waiting_threads_start" << std::endl;

    while( true ) {
        {
            //-----------------------------------
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> my_lock(my_mutex);

            while (global_int == 0)
            {
                my_cond_var.wait(my_lock);
            }
            --global_int;
            std::cout << "thread_id:" <<  std::this_thread::get_id() << ":" << id << std::endl; 
           //-------------------------------------------------------         
        }   
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    }
}
```

Здесь не хватает логики завершения работы, но мы ее опустим для простоты.

Далее, если вы посмотрите на участок кода, между комментарием //-----
то заметите, что выполняется он под захваченным мьютексом. Это значит, что выполняется в один момент только один поток. То есть, когда вы находитесь здесь, главный поток либо уже установил переменную `global_int` в ненулевое значение и цикл ожидания не будет выполнятся, либо еше нет, но тогда вы не пропустите сигнала на `std::condition_variable` поскольку послать сигнал основной поток сможет только тогда, когды вы отпустите мьютекс и находитесь в режиме ожидания.

Следует заметить, что событие, которое вы ожидаете, это не сигнал на `std::condition_vazriable`, а состояние, когда `global_int` не равно нулю. С данной логикой событие вы не пропустите, вне зависимости от того, получили вы сигнал от `std::condition_variable` или нет.

Кроме того, основная функция не должна устанавливать `global_int` в значение 1, а должна увеличивать ее на 1. Вы должны понять, что событие завязано на переменную `global_int` и она в данном случае определяет, какое количество работы стоит в очереди. `std::condition_variable` здесь вспомогательное средство, и вы не должны строить свою логику на количестве вызовов `notify_one` или `notify_all` - это лишь средство сообщить ожидающим потокам, что состояние изменилось.

Comment: пара неточностей: (1) «*атомарно переводит поток в режим ожидания события и разблокирует мьютекс*» — на самом деле эта операция не атомарна, но гарантируется, что события пробуждения поступившие между этими двумя действиями не будут потеряны. (2) «*Причем шаг 3 и шаг 4 можно менять местами.*» — это почти всегда так, но если потоков ожидающих на одной условной переменной больше одного это может привести к голоданию более приоритетного процесса...

Comment: @Fat-Zer насчет атомарности тут скорее вопрос терминологии. Скажем так - это действие атомарно с точки зрения логики работы пременной, как это обеспечивается уже другой вопрос. Просто у начинающих очень часто отсутсвует понимание, как работает `std::condition_variable` и почему например вызов `wait()` требует заблокированного мьютекса.

Comment: @Slava, подскажите, а как тогда пробуждать поток, если не известно, есть ли ожидающие потоки или нет ? Ну можно сделать счетчик ожидающих потоков, но, когда мне нужно пробудить поток и в счетчики ожидающих потоков будет 0, что делать в этом случае ? В цикле крутить, пока в счетчике не появится значение больше 0 ?

Comment: @Optimus1 в том то и дело, что вам не нужно знать, есть ожидающие потоки или нет. Если потоки в данный момент не спят и отпустили мьютекс, то это значит, что в данный момент они обрабатывают задание. Далее, когда задание будет выполнено то он или они мьютекс захватят, перед тем, как уснуть на `std::condition_variable` они проверят условие, и засыпать просто не будут, поскольку оно уже выставлено. Именно поэтому важна "атомарность" отпускания мьютекса и ухода в сон на ожидании события.

Comment: @Optimus1 кстати ваша функция ожидания неправильна, она не должна сбрасывать в 0 `global_int` с новым захватом мьютекса, а уменьшать ее значение на 1 в цикле ожидания

Comment: @Optimus1  я дополнил ответ, надеюсь не слишком длинно и вы разберетесь.

Comment: @Slava, огромное спасибо! Теперь до меня дошло.